# How do I jquery part of a document?

Tags: jquery, dom

I looked at [JQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page), read FAQ and saw a lot of examples. It looks like to get a set of all elements in the document that is described by a rule, you code

```
$(rule)
```

where rule is a string whose syntax is described [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors). Document seems to be a hidden input parameter. Can I do the same with a subtree of the DOM? If I have a DOM element, can I code something like

```
element.$(rule)
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(rule, element)
```

From the docs:

> jQuery(expression, context)
>
> The core functionality of jQuery
>   centers around this function.
>   Everything in jQuery is based upon
>   this, or uses this in some way. The
>   most basic use of this function is to
>   pass in an expression (usually
>   consisting of CSS), which then finds
>   all matching elements.
>
> By default, if no context is
>   specified, $() looks for DOM elements
>   within the context of the current HTML
>   document. If you do specify a context,
>   such as a DOM element or jQuery
>   object, the expression will be matched
>   against the contents of that context.
>
> See Selectors for the allowed CSS
>   syntax for expressions.

Comment: Thanks, [Core/jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#expressioncontext) document explains everything. What I missed is that $() is a shorthand for jQuery(). Where is it stated?

Comment: Well, http://docs.jquery.com/Core/$ redirects to Core/jQuery, and some of this examples on the page use $().

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this. If you have a document like this:

```
<html>
<body>
  <p>Test</p>
  <div id="box">
    <p>Hi There</p>
    <div id="subbox">
      <p>Bye</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>Boo</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And you only wanted the paragraphs inside box, you could [`specify a context`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#expressioncontext) to the search:

```
$('p','#box'); // only find paragraphs inside of #box
```

Or you could use functions such as [`find`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/find#expr) or [`children`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/children#expr):

```
$('#box').find('p'); // will return both the paragraphs inside of #box

$('#box').children('p'); // will only return the immediate children
```

Instead of having really long selectors I usually like to separate the search terms as much as possible because a) I think it makes more sense to think of it this way, b) it helps jQuery out with parsing so it is slightly faster. So whenever I only want to search part of a document, I sometimes use a combination of the context and the additional functions:

```
$(myelement, mygreatercontext).find(myrefinedsearch);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(element).find(rule)`